# Hough Line Transform on Live Video causes Breakpoint?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run a hough line transform on a live video feed. First the feed is ran through   a canny edge detector which works and outputs perfectly, then I run the image though a hough line transform and it causes "windows has trigger a breakpoint in openCv.exe." If you look at the frozen program you can see that the program did the hough transform but then it freezes, a box pops up with the "Windows has triggered...." error

Any ideas?

CODE:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    namedWindow( "Edges", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL ); 
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

    Mat frame; 
    Mat out; 
    Mat out2;
    Mat canny;
    Mat hough;
    while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        imshow("Source",frame);
        GaussianBlur( frame, out, Size(5, 5), 0, 0 );
        cvtColor( out ,out2, CV_BGR2GRAY ); // produces out2, a one-channel image (CV_8UC1)
     Canny( out2, canny, 100, 200, 3 ); // the result goes to out2 again,but since it is still one channel it is fine
     imshow( "Canny", canny );


 cvtColor(canny, hough, CV_GRAY2BGR);
  vector<Vec4i> lines;
  HoughLinesP(canny, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 100, 10 );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
   Vec4i l = lines[i];
   //line( hough, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
   cout << Point(l[0], l[1]) << endl;
   cout << Point(l[2], l[3]) << endl;
  }

  imshow("Lines", hough);

      if( !frame.data ) break;


        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 'c' ) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

LOG OUTPUT

```
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\openCV\Release\openCV.exe', Symbols loaded.
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WRusr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_core246.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_imgproc246.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui246.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.16384_none_7c55c866aa0c3ff0\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdmo.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qcap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksproxy.ax', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vidcap.ax', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Kswdmcap.ax', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc42.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1f8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qedit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.16384_none_dadf89385bc5c7d7\GdiPlus.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xccc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dim700.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'openCV.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1684) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'openCV.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xc38) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'openCV.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'openCV.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'openCV.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x22b8) has exited with code 1950154752 (0x743d0000).
HEAP[openCV.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 028A0000, 037EBA68 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in openCV.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in openCV.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while openCV.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
HEAP[openCV.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 028A0000, 037ABB28 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in openCV.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in openCV.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while openCV.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
HEAP[openCV.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 028A0000, 037AD0D8 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in openCV.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in openCV.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while openCV.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
The program '[8248] openCV.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, I guess the problem is that your program links the opencv as DLL, and its linkage to CRT is different from that in your EXE.

So the vector you pass to `HoughLinesP` allocates memory inside the DLL module, and then you free outside.  Due to different linkage of the CRT, its memory pool is also not the same, so you get into trouble.

and the solution is simple, just got to project **property page** -> **C/C++** -> **Code Generation**, then change **Runtime Library** to same value as your opencv project.